# SwiftUI: Nested Lists in HStack - Unequal Heights and Visibility Issue

Tags: swiftui

I am currently working on a SwiftUI project where I need to implement a two-column layout using HStack with nested List views. The issue I'm facing is that the nested lists are not appearing correctly; their heights seem too small, and the content is not fully visible.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```swift
List {
    Section(header: Text("Rule editor")) {
        // view1
    }
    Section(header: Text("Functions")) {
        // view2
    }

    HStack {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Card In")) {
                // view3
            }
        }

        List {
            Section(header: Text("Card Out")) {
                // view4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried adjusting the frame, row heights, and padding, but the issue persists. The nested lists' heights seem to be affected by the content or the default layout behavior, leading to visibility problems.

Can someone guide me on how to ensure equal heights for both nested lists and make their content fully visible in this two-column layout?

Comment: I don’t think lists are designed to be nested. Can you explain why you need nested lists?

Comment: Instead of `List`s, how about using `(Lazy)VStack`s instead?

Comment: Agree with above -- nested `List` is not a good idea and will only lead to problems.

Comment: Thanks, I removed nesting and that helped